# simple cms - symfony

Tags: symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4

I'm in the process of writing a small/basic CMS system using Symfony 1.4 and Doctrine.

I have a several models, mainly for user management, with a couple of others to list products etc. I have created in my schema a model, 'Pages' and I have several fields to output data, i.e `description` , `page_title`

The problem I'm having is how I'd actually implement this? I have approx 10 pages and each are different in terms of page content and layout (a part from the navigation menu/header).

I have seen `Diem` and `Apostrophenow`, but both seem to edit the pages `in-context`, I'd rather do this in the admin.

I have also seen `slots` used in symfony, would this be a good route to go down, i.e. defining slots in my `layout.php` file and then 'enabling/disabling' them via an admin panel on a per page basis?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apostrophe is very flexible in terms of slots. You can define different slot types and areas that hold predefined set of slots. I'd go ahead with Apostrophe, instead of writing my own. It's worth it.

You may want to turn off some plugins to keen things simple and speed up cache recreation. For example sfFeed2Plugin, sfSyncContentPlugin, apostropheBlogPlugin.

Comment: Having looked at it, it seems to have in-context editing, ie. no admin backed. I'd rather have some sort of page/template/slot management admin interface.